# What is the reason for this zig zag loss curve

Tags: machine-learning

I train a resnet18 (also resnet50 and resnet152) to classify 1500 different vehicles and the loss curve has this weird shape. At the beginning of every epoch there is a huge jump. What could be the reason? I use cross entropy loss. And it is the average loss per batch.

[image: Loss]

[image: Accuracy]

Answer (score 3):

One thing that can cause this is if you fail to randomize the order in which training samples are presented to the network.  The solution is to randomize the order of training samples.